# c# Asp .Net Ajax send String - 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have problem with passing parameters beteen view a controller.
I send serialized class to string as parameter in ajax.BeginForm, and i got error  **414 (Request-URI Too Long)** . 
Serialize of procedure works correectly, i have use it on another functions of applications.

I try to set

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength = "1048576" enable="true" />
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxQueryString="1073741824" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

bat still i got error with message '414 Uri Url is too long'

below is a part of code
Views:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "Table", new { data = Model.Serialize() }, 
    new AjaxOptions() {UpdateTargetId = "TableId", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "TestOnSukcess" }, 
    new { contentType = "application/json"}))
{
...
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class TableController : Controller
    {
       public void Update(Record arg, String data = null)
       {
          ...
       }
    }
```

error show in chrome browser after posting ajax form and call controller method (Update), where i do mistake? 
For example serialized class have a 16844 lengths.

Sorry for my bad English :c

Comment: Why in the world do you want to send the whole model to the view and then send it all back again unchanged?

Comment: because model contain List of fields (<input...>), which who is displayed on view, and i dont have any possibility to display again on the view

Comment: What are you talking about?